# How to prevent the `#!/bin/bash: not found` error when calling a script from Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

i have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stretch-backports

MAINTAINER c33s

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
COPY provision-base.sh /root/provision-base.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/provision-base.sh && /root/provision-base.sh
```

why do i get the following error running it:

```
...snip...
/root/provision-base.sh: 1: /root/provision-base.sh: ﻿#!/bin/bash: not found
...snip...
```

- the file exists `RUN ls /root/provision-base.sh` shows it
- `RUN which bash` also shows that bash is installed
- the script gets started and continues after the error
- the build succeeds

build log on dockerhub:https://hub.docker.com/r/c33s/debian/builds/bd6g8cqr2rtys9a2gguehcw/ (snip of the build log also on pastebin https://pastebin.com/6x1UK53H)

Comment: Windows line endings?

Comment: the file is encoded utf8 with unix line endings. https://github.com/c33s-dockers/main/blob/e7adc368713c611b4b192809deb1420711b3fbde/debian/provision-base.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect now that the problem is in the internal file format of your script.

It might have happened when downloading it through a web browswer. At least this is what I got after downloading `/debian/provision-base.sh` through Chrome on Mac OS:

```
$ file *
provision-base.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
script-with-good-format.sh:   Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII
```

and then the same error occurs for me when building the Dockerfile.

The `BOM` can be removed like this, which should solve the problem:

```
awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' provision-base.sh > provision-base.sh
```

Comment: the default setting auf my notepad++ is utf-8 without bom, so i don't know why all my files where encoded utf8 with bom, had not searched there for a problem. i just converted them in notepad++. to utf8 without bom. works like charm now.

Answer (score 4):

Bash is often in different places on different systems. Often at `/bin/bash`, but on this container it's located here:

```
 % docker run -it debian:stretch-backports
root@bb01a3db779e:/# type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash
```

The `env` command is more predictable, and can be used to locate other programs in the shebang line. So try this in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: already tried both before `#!/usr/bin/bash: not found` `#!/usr/bin/env: not found`

Comment: You have to "fish". Or experiment.  My image, it was located at "/bin/sh".  #linuxFlavorsVary